# Best practice for sequential url requests nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've got a list of urls i need to request from an API, however in order to avoid causing a lot of load i would ideally like to perform these requests with a gap of x seconds. Once all the requests are completed, certain logic that doesnt matter follows.

There are many ways to go about it, i've implemented a couple.

A) Using a recursive function that goes over an array that holds all the urls and calls itself when each request is done and a timeout has happened

B) Setting timeouts for every request in a loop with incremental delays and returning promises which upon resolution using Promise.all execute the rest of the logic and so on.

**These both work**. However, what would you say is the recommended way to go about this? This is more of an academic type of question and as im doing this to learn i would rather avoid using a library that abstracts the juice.

Comment: Are you even sure there is any benefit in splitting it? While making spaces would not make all the loads at same time, the total amount of data send and received won’t change, and as long as total load time is lesser than seconds no one would notice anything.

Comment: Recommended way can mean a lot of things. Do you mean performance wise? Do you mean difficulty of implementing it?

Comment: `recommended way` - I would say, of those two, A or B, I would probably, in a production environment, if I had to choose, I would use neither of those "patterns"

Comment: -at Akxe, each requests triggers a very heavy processing procedure so the load isnt really in the network but the CPU.

-at maxpaj I should have been more specific on this. I mean good code wise. My solutions seem hacky to me but i wouldnt know what i dont know.

-at JaromandaX No offence but all you're telling me is "dont use those" but not why or offering a better alternative on this :/

Comment: The A solution does not guarantee x amount per period started, it would start x amount and when they are done start another x amount. Solution B is what I use in my answer but using timeout in a function called `later` and schedule the function that returns a promise at the earliest time available. Schedule per period allows x amount per period and doesn't care when they are done. But you can also limit active, this will not allow more than x amount to be active and as one resolves another one is started.

Comment: @Akxe I had to put an instance of solr on a test server and that one would be taken out of the cluster every day. Later found out that someone was running a crawler that had no limit, it somehow chocked the network so bad that zookeeper gave up on trying to ping pong that instance. Not sure if the same would be allowed on a Linux machine but this was Windows and the crawler was a .net app (solr is Java). So there is a benefit for throttling long running processes when you want or need to be civil to other things running on that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions are almost identical. Thought I would choose a bit different approach. I would make initial promise and sleep promise function, then I would chain them together.

```
function sleep(time){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

ApiCall()
.then(sleep(1000))
.then(nextApiCall())...
```

Or more modular version

```
var promise = Promise.resolve()
myApiCalls.forEach(call => {
    promise = promise.then(call).then(() => sleep(1000))
})
```

In the end, go with what you understand, what make you most sense and what you will understand in month. The one that you can read best is you preferred solution, performance won’t matter here.

Comment: There should be a possible solution with async/await, witch might be neat, but I can’t figure it out...

Comment: thanks thats a good response. this is for learning purposes and not production so im mainly looking for a more readable and elegant way of coding this like the one you suggested, not so much grasping for performance because as you say, it probably wont be a significant difference anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to [throttle](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L277-L340) per period.

If you want all urls to be processed even when some fail you could catch the failed ones and pick them out in the result.

Code would look something like this:

```
const Fail = function(details){this.details=details;};
twoPerSecond = throttlePeriod(2,1000);
urls = ["http://url1","http://url2",..."http://url100"];
Promise.all(//even though a 100 promises are created only 2 per second will be started
  urls.map(
    (url)=>
      //pass fetch function to twoPerSecond, twoPerSecond will return a promise
      //  immediately but will not start fetch untill there is an available timeslot
      twoPerSecond(fetch)(url)
      .catch(e=>new Fail([e,url]))
  )
)
.then(
  results=>{
    const failed = results.map(result=>(result&&result.constuctor)===Fail);
    const succeeded = results.map(result=>(result&&result.constuctor)!==Fail);
  }
)
```